# How to make add a square box inside another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, documentation, grids, points

Is it possible to create the picture shown below in LaTex? I am fairly new to this software and any help would be greatly appreciated. I know how the code to start off the square but I'm not sure how to add the squares and dots inside them.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimalist solution.  Needs no extra packages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \fbox{$\bullet$} & \fbox{$\bullet$} & \fbox{$\circ$} \\
        \fbox{$\circ$} & \fbox{$\bullet$} & \fbox{$\circ$} \\
        \fbox{$\circ$} & \fbox{$\circ$} & \fbox{$\bullet$} \\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice...the minimalist code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, not as minimal as Henri Menke solution, but not too verbose

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (a) [draw, matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw, anchor=center},
row sep=1mm, column sep=1mm]{%
\bullet & \bullet & \circ\\
\circ & \bullet & \circ\\
\circ & \circ & \bullet\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This shoud be usefull

```
\begin{center}
%\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[
        box1/.style={draw=black, thick, rectangle,rounded corners, minimum height=0.75cm, minimum width=0.75cm}]
\draw[black,dashed,fill=red!30] (-.5,-3.2) rectangle (3.2,.5);
\node[box1, fill=green!30] (c1) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c1] (c2) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c2] (c3) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c3] (c4) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c4] (c5) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c5] (c6) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c6] (c7) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c7] (c8) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c8] (c9) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c9] (c10) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c10] (c11) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, right=.125cm of c11] (c12) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, below=.125cm of c12] (c13) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c13] (c14) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c14] (c15) {};
\node[box1, fill=green!30, left=.125cm of c15] (c15) {};
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you completed the example to make the code directly compilable.